# Trigger notification from Terminal on Chrome OS

Tags: bash, terminal, chromium-os

I was wondering if there's a way to trigger notification from Terminal or bash script on Chrome OS. Similar tools are already available on most other desktop operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hterm supports the OSC-777 sequence (from rxvt-unicode) for generating notifications:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/HEAD/hterm/doc/ControlSequences.md#OSC

An example script that you can use:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/HEAD/hterm/etc/hterm-notify.sh